# Can $Rx$ be contained in $I$ for some nonzero $x\in S$, if $I:=\langle R\setminus S\rangle$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be any ring and let any set of elements $S\subset R$ (proper) be such that $0_R,1_R\in S$ with some other elements of $R$.  Now, define $$I:=\langle R\setminus S\rangle=\langle\{a\in R: a\notin S\}\rangle.$$ That is, $I$ is generated by the set of elements not in $S$.

Question: Is there a possibility some left ideal $Rx$ to be contained in $I$ for some nonzero $x\in S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{2\}$. Then $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $4\in I\cap S$.

Comment: Suppose that there is an extra condition on $\{R\setminus S\}$ that the unity can not be in $\{R\setminus S\}$.  i.e., $1\notin\{R\setminus S\}$.

Comment: @Sulayman You mean that $I$ is assumed to be proper?

Comment: Yes, at all times, it is assumed that $I\subset R$ as a left ideal

Comment: @Sulayman Then it's even easier.

Comment: Thanks, I am waiting for a concrete conclusion on whether there can be any possibility of some left ideal $Rx$ to be contained in $I$ for some nonzero $x\in S$?

Comment: @Sulayman $4\in I\cap S$ and $4\ne 0$. End: the ideal generated by $4$ is ***obviously*** contained in $I$.

Comment: Sorry!  We have that $I:=\langle R\setminus S\rangle$.  So, $x$ is picked from the complement of the generating set of $I$, i.e., $x\in S$.  With $I\subset R$,

Comment: @Sulayman Doesn't $4\in S$? Every integer except $2$ belongs to $S$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80769/discussion-between-sulayman-and-egreg).

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and let $S=\left\{E_{i,j}\mid 1\leq i,j\leq 3\right\}\cup \left\{0_R,1_R\right\}$ where $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix with zeroes everywhere and a $1$ at position $(i,j)$. Then $I=\left\langle R\setminus S\right\rangle=R$. Clearly $RE_{1,1}$ is contained in $I$.

Comment: Suppose that there is an extra condition on $\{R\setminus S\}$ that the unity can not be in $\{R\setminus S\}$.  i.e., $1\notin\{R\setminus S\}$.